# How does bootstrap evauate the media-breakpoint-up parameters?

Tags: sass, bootstrap-4, scss-mixins

Reading the documentation of bootstrap, I see the following code snippets:

```
    @include media-breakpoint-up(sm) { ... }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(md) { ... }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(lg) { ... }
    @include media-breakpoint-up(xl) { ... }
```

Are those global Sass variables (`sm`, `md`, `lg`, `xl`) and Bootstrap uses them internally to create the breakpoints? Where does this magic/transofrmation happen?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap documentation suggests that,

```
(extra small devices - screen width less than 576px)
sm- (small devices - screen width equal to or greater than 576px)
md- (medium devices - screen width equal to or greater than 768px)
lg- (large devices - screen width equal to or greater than 992px)
xl- (xlarge devices - screen width equal to or greater than 1200px)
```

So that's where its breaks when it encounters sm md lg and xl

In bootstrap-grid.css this is where media queries are defined

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 540px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 720px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 960px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    max-width: 1140px;
  }
}
```

and below is where sm classes are defined and they are enclosed in a media-query which specifies the device size, lets say we are rendering our html on a small device the below media query is true and so these css classes will be applied, other classes md, lg and xl are not applied as the media queries in which they are enclosed won't be true. In your html template you need to specify all possibilities like col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6 col-xl-6(meaning allocate 12 grid spaces in sm and md screens and 6 grids in lg and xl screens for given column)

```
@media (min-width: 576px) {
  .col-sm {
    -ms-flex-preferred-size: 0;
    flex-basis: 0;
    -ms-flex-positive: 1;
    flex-grow: 1;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-auto {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .col-sm-1 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 8.333333%;
    max-width: 8.333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-2 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 16.666667%;
    max-width: 16.666667%;
  }
  .col-sm-3 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 25%;
    flex: 0 0 25%;
    max-width: 25%;
  }
  .col-sm-4 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    flex: 0 0 33.333333%;
    max-width: 33.333333%;
  }
  .col-sm-5 {
    -ms-flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
    flex: 0 0 41.666667%;
    max-width: 41.666667%;
  }
....
....
```

Comment: I think this does not answer my question. Where does bootstrap handle this? Bootstraps iterates through my code and checks for all those parameters? That was the question.

Comment: Although I am not sure if this answers your question, all grid related css classes are in bootstrap-grid.css and when we include bootstrap files in our project it applies the css classes directly when it encounters media break points.

Comment: not yet, I still don't get whre is the mechanism of bootstrap to replace those variables (xs, sm, md, lg, xl)

Comment: sm md lg xl are not variables/classes on their own. They are often used along with columns, margins, padding, buttons, offsets etc. If you carefully inspect bootstrap-grid.css, at the top, the media break points are defined and based on that containers size is set . If you scroll down a bit more you can see all css classes corresponding to sm,md, lg,xl. css classes are applied just like any normal html and css files would work.

Comment: that is still not what I meant, but I found where the logic happens. It's in the `_breakpoints.scss` line 58.

Comment: ok glad you found what you were looking for :) I have added a bit more explanation just in case if anyone else wants!